# How to section recyclerView based on Dates, and change the sections dynamically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**I want to section my recycler view based on the dates**(days of the week or by month etc) of the items inside. They are a set of custom objects that i manage using realm. I have made use of [this](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/4c189fb1124df4556058) class to achieve the sections.

**The problem** with it is that you set the amount of sections in the adapters constructor(this only happens once) and you can't redefine or change the sections dynamically should all the items in a section be deleted or new items added that require their own sections.

I have a listener for the objects that notifies me of any changes, and they all have their own date attributes in millis, that I can easily convert to day of the week using the java calendar class.

How do I go about implementing this feature?
Cheers